# It is said that the dual Meissner effect can explain confinement, but where is the Higgs?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs, magnetic-monopoles, confinement, solitons

It is said that the dual Misner effect can explain confinement. This refers to when the monopole field acquires a v.e.v..

The t'Hooft-Polyakov monopole arises in a theory with a Higgs. So how does the monopole arise in QCD, say, and how does the dual Meissner effect work there?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_superconductor_model). [Ripka](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0310102).

Comment: Kondo, Shibata,  Shinohara,  & Kato,  (2011). "Non-Abelian dual superconductor picture for quark confinement", *Physical Review* **D83** (11), 114016.  No Higgs-like field!

Comment: @CosmasZachos. Also, the Wu-Yang monopole arises in pure gauge theory.

Comment: Yes, of course. But one does not look at monopoles, per se; one looks at suitable operators....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cosmas has commented, the answer is contained on page 2 of the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1599.pdf.